# python syntax error in dict comprehension

Tags: python

Here is what I'm trying to do:

I want to count letters frequency in a sentence.

Here is my code in python so far:

```
for i in line:
    if i in my_count.keys():
        my_count[i]+=1
    else:
        my_count[i]=1
```

Is there any way to fulfill the same goal with dict comprehension, the same we would do with list comprehension?

I have thought at something such as :

```
my_count = { x:(my_count[x]+=1) for x in line if x in my_count else x:1 }
```

But this does not pass the syntax check (SyntaxError: invalid syntax at the +=).

Thanks for your help and advices!

Comment: Is there a reason that you're not using `collections.Counter`?  (Sometimes it's forbidden for pedagogical reasons on assignments, but otherwise it's the natural choice.)

Comment: No, I just didn't know about that. Many thanks for your tip!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Counter in collections](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) seems to accomplish this.

```
In [1]: line = 'the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'
In [2]: from collections import Counter
In [3]: c = Counter(line)
In [4]: c
Out[4]: Counter({' ': 8, 'o': 4, 'e': 3, 'h': 2, 'r': 2, 'u': 2, 't': 2, 'a': 1, 'c': 1, 'b': 1, 'd': 1, 'g': 1, 'f': 1, 'i': 1, 'k': 1, 'j': 1, 'm': 1, 'l': 1, 'n': 1, 'q': 1, 'p': 1, 's': 1, 'w': 1, 'v': 1, 'y': 1, 'x': 1, 'z': 1})
```

Comment: Pet peeve: the phrase is **jumps**, otherwise there's no 's'.